# how to get a particular column value from a list view on click of a row from that list view

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

```
//code to dislplay item in list view
            myList= controller.searchprop(prop_no.getText().toString());
            if (myList.size() != 0) {
                ListView lv = getListView();
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Search_Equipments.this, myList,
                        R.layout.searchview, new String[]{"old_prop", "new_prop", "serial_no", "item_name","responsibility_center"}, new int[]{
                        R.id.txtsearch_old_prop, R.id.txtsearch_new_prop, R.id.txtsearch_serial_no, R.id.txtsearch_item_name, R.id.txtsearch_center});
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(Search_Equipments.this,"No Records Available, Please enter valid value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            HashMap<String,String> map =(HashMap<String,String>)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //Cursor c = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String prop = map.put(DBController.prop_no1);

            //String prop = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position - 1));
            Toast.makeText(Search_Equipments.this, prop, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

can someone help how to get specific data in a row from listview after i click. or debug my code. thanks :)
can someone help how to get specific data in a row from listview after i click. or debug my code. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more elegant solutions but I ran into this issue recently (I am new to android development) and came up with a solution.

Within your `onItemClick()` listener, place the following code to access data within the view:

```
//invoke a HashMap of the item at the given position using Parent.
HashMap<String, String> info = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

//Then access individual data items within the hash map using the key
String personName = info.get("first_name");

//Or change data within the hash map
info.put("first_name", "new first name");
```

I hope that this answers your question (If I understood it correctly).